# Consolidating similar packages

Tags: package-writing

Are there any efforts being made towards consolidating packages with overlapping features? If I created a package that could provide extra features to another package, is it expected that I share this with the other package writer instead of rolling out my own package?

Comment: That is just a matter of social interaction and so probably off topic. Some people send feature requests to existing package maintainers, some people publish variant packages, some people arrange a changeover of maintenance and so take over and extend old packages. The issues are same whether the code is written in TeX or Fortran, there are not really any TeX specific issues.

Comment: If you are convinced you have code that would be a real improvement to an existing package, why not contact the package author to see if you could work together. Some TeX contributors use github, so you could make a pull request (or whatever you do with github); many do not, but I imagine would be happy to receive suggestions. The community is, I think, admirably open and welcoming. The one time I wrote to a prominent package author (a recent update had created a bug), he was very grateful for the bug report and fixed the problem immediately.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think there is a TeX-specific question here, which is, "Does the TeX community have a standard process (unique to TeX) for new people to contribute to existing packages?" And the answer, I think, is no. (Or "e-mail"?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Compared to submitting Debian packages for example, or emacs or ruby or haskell packages through their distribution systems.

Comment: @AndrewCashner are the issues any different there? making a new debian package isn't so different to uploading a new package to ctan. Either way if you want to actually extend an existing one then the issues are about social interaction (and copyright) not the mechanics of making the changes. (But it's marginal and I didn't actually vote the question as off topic, just commented that it might be)